# Query SQL com múltiplas condições WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

Estava tentando fazer um sistema de busca que pesquisasse em 2 campos da tabela ao mesmo tempo e pudesse ter várias condições no WHERE do SELECT, pesquisei em vários lugares e achei essa query, mas quando fui rodar deu o erro:

"Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean".

Alguém pode me ajudar a identificar o problema por favor?

[image: Foto]

Comment: Tira aquele último `OR` que da erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Coloca o código como texto e não como imagem.

Comment: Se mudares um pouco a tua pergunta, este exemplo pode ser útil para outros utilizadores que pesquisem por isto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tua query não é uma query válida, e por isso [o retorno do `mysqli_query` é um `BOOLEAN`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues), neste caso `false`.

Tens outros problemas no código. Fechas o ciclo aqui `foreach ($v as $key => $value);`, em vez de adicionares na query mais condicoes `OR` para cada item em `$pesquisa`.

Penso que o que queres é ter múltiplas possibilidades para a `descricao` e `grau` consoante o que foi pesquisado, tipo `algo para pesquisar` iria criar 3 combinações, uma para cada palavra.

```
$pesquisa = $_POST["pesquisa"];
$v = explode(" ", $pesquisa);

$condicoes = []; // um array para guardar todas as condicoes
foreach ($v as $key => $value) {
    // adicionar ao array uma condicao por cada valor passado em $pesquisa
    $condicoes[] = "descricao LIKE '%{$value}%' OR grau LIKE '%{$value}%'";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM lentes WHERE " . implode(" OR ", $condicoes);

$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

// ... o resto do teu código
```

---

**Como funciona**

O PHP come arrays ao pequeno-almoço, dai ser uma das estruturas de dados mais úteis da linguagem, especialmente quando estás a usar um estilo de código mais procedural, mesmo quando usas objectos será útil, sugeria que te familiarizasses sobre o que é possível lendo a [documentação do PHP sobre arrays](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.array.php).

O código que coloquei no `foreach` apenas está a adicionar items ao array, por exemplo, imagina que `$pesquisa` é `algo para pesquisar`.

```
// aqui dividimos a string "algo para pesquisar" em cada espaço
$v = explode(" ", $pesquisa);

// isto cria um array assim
// Array
// (
//     [0] => algo
//     [1] => para
//     [2] => pesquisar
// )

// por cada palavra, adicionamos um item ao nosso array condicoes
$condicoes = []; 
foreach ($v as $key => $value) {
    $condicoes[] = "descricao LIKE '%{$value}%' OR grau LIKE '%{$value}%'";
}

// $condicoes, depois deste ciclo será
// Array
// (
//     [0] => descricao LIKE '%algo%' OR grau LIKE '%algo%'
//     [1] => descricao LIKE '%para%' OR grau LIKE '%para%'
//     [2] => descricao LIKE '%pesquisar%' OR grau LIKE '%pesquisar%'
// )
```

Podemos usar o [implode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php), que é o oposto do explode(), para transformar $condicoes num string, e até podemos (devemos!) verificar se há $condicoes (ou seja, se algo foi adicionado ao array.

```
$sql_condicoes = ""; // o SQL das condições é vazio caso não existam condicoes
if (count($condicoes) > 0) {
    $sql_condicoes = " WHERE " . implode(" OR ", $condicoes);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM lentes" . $sql_condicoes;
```

Comment: Valeuuu, funcionou direitinho aqui :D               
Mas poderia me explicar como funciona o $condicoes = []; por favor?

Comment: Adicionei alguma informação de como o código funciona e alguns links para a documentação, sugeria mesmo dar um olhada :)

Answer (score 2):

O `mysqli_query` retorna um objeto em caso de sucesso e caso dê falha retorna um boolean `FALSE`, ou seja, muito provável que sua `$resultado` seja `false` e você está tentando fazer um `fetch_array()` em um boolean (*call to a member function on boolean*).

O que você pode fazer pra ajudar no debug disso é fazer um :

```
if (!$resultado) {
   // faz um tratamento de erro pra saber qual erro deu
   // e retorna algo para parar a execução deste script
}
```

E então você só irá fazer `$resultado->fetch_array()` caso `$resultado` não seja `FALSE`.